# How to use Bugzilla behind a reverse proxy Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, bugzilla

We have a bugzilla service sitting on a internal server. We are trying to make it accessible from outside via an Apache server which will act as a proxy.

So far, with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_html, we can get Bugzilla served transparently through the proxy server. The problem is with login.

When the user submits his credentials, he receives the confirmation page that he is identified. But as soon as he clicks to a link, he is not anymore and is redirected to the identification page.

I guess that somehow, the cookie/session info are lost.
Is this something to be fixed on Apache proxy side? or in Bugzilla config?

Thank you for your help.

this the vhost config of the Apache proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyHTMLEnable On 
 ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
 LogLevel Info
 ProxyRequests off
 ProxyPass /bugzilla/ http://bugzilla.internal_domain.com/
 ProxyPassReverse /bugzilla/ http://bugzilla.internal_domain.com/
 ProxyHTMLURLMap http://bugzilla.internal_domain.com /bugzilla
 ProxyHTMLURLMap / /bugzilla
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you look at your browser's behavior and determine what is occurring?  My inkling is that something's getting broken about the links by the `ProxyHTMLURLMap` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having this problem on a university network 10 years ago. The 'fix' in that case was to add bugzilla.mozilla.org to the list of sites which bypassed the reverse proxy.

I tell you this so you know that a) it may be a long-standing problem, and b) working around it may be the easiest fix.

(Before I got it fixed by the network admins, my fix was to have a macro which inserted my username and password and clicked Enter, the 500 times per day I had to do it...)